# How to trigger the hidden field using VBA in web Page

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, automation

I had Automated Data entry in a web page using VBA but there is a field which is hidden its only pop up if you select date more than 1 month old. While i am entering the date using VBA to it its not showing hidden field but when i am manually entering the same date its showing the hidden field where i need to mentioned the some reason.
My VBA Code

```
IE.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtInvoicedt").Value = Sheet5.Range("B13").Value
```

Web Page Code

```html
<td>Invoice Date</td>
<td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtInvoicedt" type="text" 
   id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtInvoicedt" autocomplete="off"  
   onblur="lostClr(this);if(this.value!=&#39;&#39;){return 
   checkDt(this,&#39;invdt&#39;);}" onchange="check_idate()" onkeypress="return 
   false;" style="width:100px;">
   <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbldelay_reason" style="visibility: 
      hidden;">Delay Reason :</span>
   <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtdelay_reason" type="text" 
      id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtdelay_reason" style="visibility: hidden;">
   <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblreason" style="color: red; visibility: 
      hidden;">*Min 15 chars</span>
   <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btndelay_attach" type="button"
      id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btndelay_attach" class="button_1" style="border-style: none;
      width: 350px; visibility: hidden;" value="Attach/Upload CGM&#39;s Approval"
      onclick="return openDelay_approval()">
   <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdndelay_attach"
      id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdndelay_attach">
   <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdndelay_attach_id"
      id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdndelay_attach_id">
```

Before Selection of Date: [image: Before Selection of Date]

After Selection of Date:  [image: After Selection of Date]

Comment: try `IE.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtInvoicedt").fireEvent("onblur");` after you set the date.

Comment: Nothing happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the showing hidden field function in the `onblur` event of the first input? If so, you can use `fireEvent` to fire the `onblur` event. You could refer to my sample below.

**Sample VBA code:**

```
Sub LOADIE()
    Set ieA = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ieA.Visible = True
    ieA.navigate "https://www.example.html"
    Do Until ieA.readyState = 4
       DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Set doc = ieA.Document
    doc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtInvoicedt").Value = 11
    doc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtInvoicedt").fireEvent ("onblur")
End Sub
```

**Sample HTML page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Invoice Date</div>
    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtInvoicedt" type="text"
           id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtInvoicedt" autocomplete="off"
           onblur="check_date()" onkeypress="return false;" style="width:100px;">
    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbldelay_reason" style="visibility: hidden;">Delay Reason:</span>
    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtdelay_reason" type="text"
           id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtdelay_reason" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <script>
        function check_date() {
            var a = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtInvoicedt").value;
            if (a >= 10) {
                document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbldelay_reason").style.visibility = "visible";
                document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtdelay_reason").style.visibility = "visible";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbldelay_reason").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtdelay_reason").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing happening

Comment: Is there any error when you execute the code above? I want to confirm with you how the hidden field is shown in the website? Is the showing function in the `onblur` event or in the `onchange` event? If you use my sample HTML page to test then you'll find the vba code can work. It could be better if you can provide more detailed web page code.